# How to set workflow variable with the result of an action in SharePoint Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that I'm working on SharePoint 2010 and I've built a custom action and it has an outbound parameter of ActionResult.

I want to be able to set a work flow variable to the value of this outbound parameter. I can't see to find

Comment: Are you doing this in code or SharePoint designer?

Comment: At the moment, I'm doing it in the SharePoint designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as to why I couldn't take the output variable of my custom action into the list was because of an incorrect DesignerType value in the .actions file.

Here is the old code:

```
<FieldBind Field="Result" DesignerType="TextArea" Text="Action result message; returns OK on success" Id="3" />
```

Here is the correct code:

```
<FieldBind Field="Result" DesignerType="ParameterNames" Text="Action result message; returns OK on success" Id="3" />
```

Once that change was made, setting the output variable into a workflow variable became very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/collect-data-from-a-user-in-a-workflow-HA010209808.aspx). You should be able to set that variable to any other variable in the workflow.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. Thank you, though.